# Recalculating xFov/yFov when size of SCNView changes?

Tags: layout, uiview, ios8, scenekit

I am currently calculating `xFov`, `yFov` for my `SCNCamera` when creating a `SCNView`. This worked find up to now, since the scene has always occupied the entire screen.

I now need to support a scenario where this is no longer the case, i.e. the cameras field of view (`xFov`, `yFov`) should be recalculated whenever the `SCNView` changes its size.

Where is the best place to insert the code that does the recalculation? If possible, I would prefer not to subclass `SCNView`.

Comment: why do you change the field of view?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I want all of the objects in my scene to be visible with a certain amount of space around them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Yosemite `NSViewController` exposes `viewWillLayout` and `viewDidLayout`. It might be the right place recalculate your fields of view.

Comment: I think you are right and this could be handled like for any other `NSView` (or `UIView`).